# Django website - make button link to a different app

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I am trying to make a button that links to another app when you click it.

For some reason, this works:

```html
<a href="{% url 'ridesharing:ride-list' %}" target="blank">Find a ride</a>
```

But this does not:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xl" style=" border-color: rgb(2,132,69); background-color: rgb(2,132,69); color: rgb(246,246,247); font-family: Verdana;font-size: large" href="{% url 'ridesharing:ride-list' %}">Find a ride</button>
```

I am using a button because I like how I can customize how it looks. How do I get the button to link to the right app.

Comment: this is not a django question. This is a CSS question. The right element to use is A and not BUTTON. You just need to style it properly. Invest in a framework like bootstrap. That will make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

Either have the button submit a form with the URL as the `action` of the form

```
<form action="{% url 'ridesharing:ride-list' %}">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl" style=" border-color: rgb(2,132,69); background-color: rgb(2,132,69); color: rgb(246,246,247); font-family: Verdana;font-size: large">Find a ride</button>
</form>
```

or add an event listener/handler that changes the `window.location.href`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-xl" style=" border-color: rgb(2,132,69); background-color: rgb(2,132,69); color: rgb(246,246,247); font-family: Verdana;font-size: large" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'ridesharing:ride-list' %}'">Find a ride</button>
```